# Spring.Net support for Linq2SQL

Tags: linq-to-sql, transactions, spring.net

May I know whether Spring.Net has built in support for Linq2SQL? Someone on Spring.Net forum mentioned there is a bridge for NHibernate. However, I might not use NHibernate at all. I am looking for direct support for Linq2Sql.

If I am using `TxScopeTransactionManager` and apply attribute based transaction to a business method which contains two linq2sql calls, will the transaction be a local transaction or escalated to a distributed transaction?

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest to use `ConnectionUtils` and its `GetConnectionTxPair` method. 
It returns a pair of database connection and transaction attached to it. When you have reference  to transaction you can explicitly enlist LINQ2SQL `DataContext` in this it by simply setting `Transaction` property of this context.

You can extend `AdoTemplate` to support LINQ2SQL:

```
public delegate T DataContextDelegate<T>(DataContext command);

public class LinqAdoTemplate : AdoTemplate
{
    public virtual T Execute<T>(DataContextDelegate<T> del)
    {
        ConnectionTxPair connTxPair = ConnectionUtils.GetConnectionTxPair(DbProvider);

        using (var context = new DataContext(connTxPair.Connection))
        {
            //downcast is a bit smelly here
            //one can throw exception though when connTxPair.Transaction is of invalid type
            context.Transaction = connTxPair.Transaction as DbTransaction;

            return del(context);
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can configure Spring.NET to inject this into your AdoTemplate-aware objects.

Comment: Nice answer, I liked reading your [blog post](http://mkarczewski.wordpress.com/2012/09/13/spring-net-linq-to-sql-transactions-support/) on this subject too.

Answer (score 0):

I was wondering the same thing.  I did a quick search here:

http://jira.springframework.org/secure/QuickSearch.jspa

and here:

http://forum.springframework.net/search.php?do=process

and nothing came up.  It's not in 1.3, and doesn't seem to be in the roadmap for 2.0.